# python: why is id(x) != id(y) when x and y are lists with equal values?

Tags: python

Why is id(a) == id(b) while id(x) != id(y) in the example below:

```
>>> a = 9
>>> b = 9
>>> id(a)
10901176
>>> id (b)
10901176
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x) != id(y)
True
>>> id(x)
11428848
>>> id(y)
12943768
```

From the python 3.6 doc I get for id() "Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."... But that doesn't explain it to me. Any ideas?

Comment: "guaranteed to be unique" does this not clear it up?

Comment: Because you've created two separate lists. They contain the same items (they're equal), but they aren't the same object (they aren't identical), as you can tell by mutating one and then looking at the other.

Comment: it refers to a memory location `a=9;b=5;b+=4; print id(a),id(b)`

Comment: The identity vs. equality distinction I believe is the most useful for grokking this as jonrsharpe mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fact that `a` and `b` integers have the same id is just a storage optimization performed by python on immutable objects (which cannot be relied upon, ex: if the numbers are big enough, `id`s can be different)

Try to change the value of `b` and you'll see that `id(b)` changes.

Of course, it's different for lists: cannot benefit from storage optimization since they're mutable: you don't want `x` to be changed when you change `y`.

Comment: This isn't even applied to *all* immutable objects; CPython preallocates `int` objects for -5 through 257 (more or less). `int`s outside this range, or other immutable objects, are not guaranteed to reuse the same object.

Comment: @chepner: yes, I have mentionned that in my answer already. Comparing ids to check for equality (or using `is`) is unreliable.